# Problem changing owner and permissions on new external drive

Tags: 20.04, permissions, disk-usage, ownership

I just installed a new 2TB external drive (Ubuntu 20.04), created one partition, and formatted it to ext4.  I mounted it to /mnt/ssk2TB.  Now the drive shows in my Nautilus file explorer, but when I use copy-paste to copy a file to the new drive, I get "permissions do now allow copy-paste."

So I changed the owner from root to my sudo user:

```
chown -R mpxt /mnt/ssk2TB
```

```
root@mpxt-Vostro-3400:/mnt/ssk2TB# ls -l
total 16
drwx------ 2 mpxt root 16384 Nov 20 10:07 lost+found
```

So now the drive is owned by mpxt, not root.  Next I changed the permissions:

```
chmod -R 755 /mnt/ssk2TB
```

```
root@mpxt-Vostro-3400:/mnt/ssk2TB# ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 mpxt root 16384 Nov 20 10:07 lost+found
root@mpxt
```

So now the permissions have been expanded.  BUT I still am not allowed to copy-paste from Nautilus.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: you need `sudo chmod -R mpxt:mpxt /mnt/ssk2TB/`  issued from your admin account (likely `mpxt`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:
`$ cat /etc/group | sed -nre "s/$USER:.*:([0-9]+)./$USER:\1/p"`
*Extract the single line that contains a numeric group ID attached to  your user name*

I'd **guess** it will print
`mpxt:1000`

With that knowledge, do
`$ sudo chown -R mpxt:1000 /mnt/ssk2TB`

.... replace `mpxt:1000` with what actually was printed above.

---

For purists:

`$ sed -nre "s/$USER:.*:([0-9]+)./$USER:\1/p"  < /etc/group`
Works just as well as that first line. But requires slightly more Linux/Bash knowledge.

Comment: It prints "root:0."  I can use that in place of mpxt:1000, but what designates that I want the new owner to be mpxt?  Thanks for your help,.

Comment: no, that won't work sadly, **you do not NORMALLY login as root**, which is what I assumed above. As I stated above `mpxt:1000` is what I'd expect to be printed, and what to use as user and group for `chown`.

Comment: On a freshly installled Linux, the normal user's "group" is 1000 - stated numerically.

Comment: we do not use root. All commands you are told need to be done using your admin account and sudo @RTC222

Comment: @Hannu - I was on as root (with sudo su).  I went back to my sudo prompt (for mpxt) and issued your command string again, and I got what you expected:  mpxt:1000.  Then I did your next step and it worked.  Now the owner is mpxt.  Thank you very much.  Your cat command is a little esoteric, I doubt I would have figured that out on my own.  I can now freely copy, move, delete files from Nautilus.  .

Comment: `cat` shows the content of a file,  and `/etc/group` (a file) contains the groups defined in your OS. The `|` means that the output is sent to `sed` for further processing.

Comment: Recommended reading for a beginner Linux user: www.tldp.org -> Bash guides.